# Regular expressions don't work as expected in bash if-else block's condition

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

My pattern defined to match in if-else block is :

```
pat="17[0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9].AUG"
nln=""
```

In my script, I'm taking user input which needs to be matched against the pattern, which if doesn't match, appropriate error messages are to be shown. Pretty simple, but giving me a hard time though. My code block from the script is this:

```
echo "How many days' AUDIT Logs need to be searched?"
read days
echo "Enter file name(s)[For multiple files, one file per line]: "
for(( c = 0 ; c < $days ; c++))
do
  read elements
  if [[  $elements =~ $pat ]];
     then
       array[$c]="$elements"
  elif [[  $elements =~ $nln ]];
     then
        echo "No file entered.Run script again. Exiting"
        exit;
  else
      echo "Invalid filename entered: $elements.Run script again. Exiting"
      exit;
  fi
done
```

The format I want from the user for filenames to be entered is this:

```
170402.AUG
```

So basically yymmdd.AUG (where y-year,m-month,d-day), with trailing or leading spaces is fine. Anything other than that should throw `"Invalid filename entered: $elements.Run script again. Exiting"` message. Also I want to check if if it is a blank line with a "Enter" hit, it should give an error saying `"No file entered.Run script again. Exiting"`

However my code, even if I enter something like "xxx" as filename, which should be throwing `"Invalid filename entered: $elements.Run script again. Exiting"`, is actually checking true against a blank line, and throwing `"No file entered.Run script again. Exiting"`

Need some help with handling the regular expressions' check with user input, as otherwise rest of my script works just fine.

Comment: Simplify. You shouldn't need more than three lines for this -- one to set the variable with the regex, one to set the variable with the value you want to test against it, one to run the test. Maybe a fourth to show the result. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on coming up with a **minimal** reproducer.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: ...that said, your pattern looks glob-style, not like a regex. If you only want the `.` to match the literal character `.`, for instance, that's what it'll do in a glob -- but in a regex, `.` matches any character at all.

Comment: I suggest to replace `$elements =~ $nln` by `$elements == ""`.

Comment: @Cyrus Or `-z $elements`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think as discussed in the comments you are confusing with the *glob* match and a `regEx` match, what you have defined as `pat` is a glob match which needs to be equated with the `==` operator as,

```
pat="17[0-1][0-9][0-9][0-9].AUG"
string="170402.AUG"

[[ $string == $pat ]] && printf "Match success\n"
```

The equivalent `~` match would be to something as

```
pat="17[[:digit:]]{4}\.AUG"
[[ $string =~ $pat ]] && printf "Match success\n"
```

As you can see the `.` in the regex syntax has been escaped to deprive of its special meaning ( to match any character) but just to use as a literal dot. The `POSIX` character class `[[:digit:]]` with a character count `{4}` allows you to match `4` digits followed by `.AUG`

---

And for the string empty check do as suggested by the comments from Cyrus, or by Benjamin.W

```
[[ $elements == "" ]]
```

(or)

```
[[ -z $elements ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not bug the user with `how many days` (who want count 15 days or like)? Also, why only one file per line? You should help the users, not bug them like microsoft...

For the start:

```
show_help() { cat <<'EOF'
bla bla....
EOF
}

show_files() { echo "${#files[@]} valid files entered: ${files[@]}"; }

while read -r -p 'files? (h-help)> ' line
do
    case "$line" in
        q) echo "quitting..." ; exit 0 ;;
        h) show_help ; continue;;
        '') (( ${#files} )) && show_files; continue ;;
        l) show_files ; continue ;;
        p) (( ${#files} )) && break || { echo "No files enterd.. quitting" ; exit 1; } ;; # go to processing
    esac
    # select (grep) the valid patterns from the entered line
    # and append them into the array
    # using the -P (if your grep know it) you can construct very complex regexes
    files+=( $(grep -oP '17\d{4}.\w{3}' <<< "$line") )
done

echo "processing files ${files[@]}"
```

Using such logic you can build really powerful and user-friendly app. Also, you can use `-e` for the `read` enable the `readline` functions (cursor keys and like)...

**But** :) Consider just create a simple script, which accepts arguments. Without any dialogs and such. example:

```
myscript -h
```

same as above, or some longer help text

```
myscript 170402.AUG 170403.AUG 170404.AUG 170405.AUG
```

will do whatever it should do with the files. Main benefit, you could use globbing in the filenames, like

```
myscript 1704*
```

and so on...

And if you really want the dialog, it could show it when someone runs the script without any argument, e.g.:

```
myscript
```

will run in interactive mode...

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. Can you also explain how the shell interprets `${#files[@]}` and a `${files[@]}` differently ?

Comment: @dig_123 You should read some bash-tutorial. :) `${#files[@]}` = number of elements in the array `files`, `${files[@]}` = list of all elements, `${#files}` = length of the 1st element... (index 0).

Comment: Thanks again. Just wanted to confirm what I understood from your code snippet is correct :)